# How to align elements inside a form

Tags: css, forms, layout, gravity-forms-plugin, layout-gravity

Calling out to css masters at SO!
I have a form that's created with gravity forms. 
[image]

The logical order of all input fields in the code is
1) Radiobuttons
2) All string/text inputs
3) textarea

I'm trying to make it so that a tab from radiobuttons leads the user to the textarea, and then to the other text input fields but that messed up the looks =\
[image]
Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: Have you tried the label for ?

Comment: How do you suggest I use the label for?

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping your original layout, but use tab order to set the order in which the tabbing happens:

http://webcheatsheet.com/HTML/controll_tab_order.php

Comment: I'm not able to change the tab index for each field, a limitation of gravity forms. (I haven't found any way of doing it atleast.)

Comment: How about wrapping the radio buttons, and textfields in a div, and push the textarea down slightly?

Comment: Another possibility:
Order of markup : Radio buttons, text fields, textarea. Then: 
Radio buttons: Float left,,
Text fields: Float Right,
Text area: float left

Comment: but then the textarea is again the last field so when tabbing from textarea you don't go to Field 4